# Searching excel column and retrieving row

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl, xlrd

So i have a list of values and I want to search a column from an excel file to see if the list items are in there and then retrieve that whole row. then I want to put it into a new excel.
Something like:
`mylist=['Monday','Wednesday','Thursday`']

```
Day        Month   Year  
Monday     June    2021
Friday     July    2021
Wednesday  May     2021
```

So i want:

```
   Day        Month   Year
   Monday      June    2021
   Wednesday   May     2021
```

Ive tried using pandas

```
import pandas as pd
mylist=['Monday','Wednesday','Thursday']
file=r'my file loc'
sheet=pd.read_excel(file)
print (sheet.loc[sheet['Day'].isin(mylist)])
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

also tried

```
for x in sheet['Day']:
  if x in mylist:
     finallist.append(x)
```

I get the following:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Ive also tried openpyxl

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
mylist=['Monday','Wednesday','Thursday']
file=r'my file loc.xlsx'
wb=load_workbook(file)
ws=wb.active
for row in ws.rows:
  if row[0].value in mylist:
    for cell in row: 
         print(cell.value)
```

I get

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: Hmmm `sheet.loc[sheet['Day'].isin(mylist)]` should be the right way. Can you show the output of `print(sheet["Day"])` ?

Comment: it prints out: 0 Monday 1 Friday 2 Wednesday

Comment: Does `sheet['Day'].isin(mylist)` properly returns a boolean series?

Comment: No i get type error series objects are mutable.

Comment: is it possible your dataframe sheet is really a series? check the dtype? visually they can look the same but sometimes I create a series accidentally and have to fix it.

Comment: the sheet is a dataframe, dtype not a series.

Comment: The `openpyxl` version will not return a `pandas` error message. Can you edit your post to show the actual error?

Comment: I figured it out, it was the list I was passing to it. It was actually a series